# Group array rows by one column and only create a subarray from another column if more than one value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, grouping

How can I group row data from a two-dimensional array and only create a subarray of another column if the respective group contains more than one value?

In other words, I need to group rows by `id` and conditionally restructure an array of arrays to have a variable depth of either 2 or 3 levels.

Input:

```
[
    ['id' => 567, 'value' => 780],
    ['id' => 676, 'value' => 743],
    ['id' => 676, 'value' => 721],
    ['id' => 234, 'value' => 766],
    ['id' => 234, 'value' => 680]
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    ['id' => 567, 'value' => 780],
    ['id' => 676, 'value' => [743, 721]],
    ['id' => 234, 'value' => [766, 680]]
]
```

Comment: Somewhat related: [Group array data by column value and only create indexed subarrays if more than one occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45264777/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to have the value as an integer when there is one value and an array when there are more?

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('id' => 567, 'value' => 780),
    array('id' => 676, 'value' => 743),
    array('id' => 676, 'value' => 721),
    array('id' => 234, 'value' => 766),
    array('id' => 234, 'value' => 680)
);

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $result[$item['id']][] = $item['value'];
}

foreach ($result as $id => $value) {
    if (count($value) > 1) {
        $output[] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'value' => $value
        );
    } else {
        $output[] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'value' => $value[0]
        );
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

If not

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('id' => 567, 'value' => 780),
    array('id' => 676, 'value' => 743),
    array('id' => 676, 'value' => 721),
    array('id' => 234, 'value' => 766),
    array('id' => 234, 'value' => 680)
);

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $result[$item['id']][] = $item['value'];
}

foreach ($result as $id => $value) {
    $output[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'value' => $value
    );
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There, all the work done for you. How easy is that!

```
//create the array as you have now
$array[0] = ['id'=>567, 'value'=>780];
$array[1] = ['id'=>676, 'value'=>743];
$array[2] = ['id'=>676, 'value'=>721];
$array[3] = ['id'=>234, 'value'=>766];
$array[4] = ['id'=>234, 'value'=>780];

print_r($array);
print chr(10).chr(10);

//create a new array with the values combined on key
$concat = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
  $i = $val['id'];
  $v = $val['value'];

  if (!is_array($concat[$i]))
    $concat[$i] = array();

  $concat[$i][] = $v;
}

print_r($concat);
print chr(10).chr(10);

//create a new array to show the data as you want.
$newarray = array();
foreach($concat as $key=>$val) {
  $t = array();
  $t['id'] = $key;

  if (count($val)==1)
    $t['value'] = $val[0];
  else {
    $t['value'] = array();
    foreach($val as $v)
      $t['value'][] = $v;
  } 

  $newarray[] = $t;
}

print_r($newarray);
print chr(10).chr(10);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 567
            [value] => 780
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 676
            [value] => 743
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 676
            [value] => 721
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 234
            [value] => 766
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 234
            [value] => 780
        )

)


Array
(
    [567] => Array
        (
            [0] => 780
        )

    [676] => Array
        (
            [0] => 743
            [1] => 721
        )

    [234] => Array
        (
            [0] => 766
            [1] => 780
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 567
            [value] => 780
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 676
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 743
                    [1] => 721
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 234
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 766
                    [1] => 780
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: If you want to edit it, atleast do it right. If you remove the `<pre>` tags, then the `print chr(10).chr(10)` lines arent realy needed either anymore. Also I cant realy say you edit made the post any better.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$array['key1'] = array(
    0=>array('id'=>567, 'value'=>780),
    1=>array('id'=>676, 'value'=>743),
    2=>array('id'=>676, 'value'=>721),
    3=>array('id'=>234, 'value'=>766),
    4=>array('id'=>234, 'value'=>780)
    );

foreach($array['key1'] as $subarray){
    $group_id = $subarray['id'];

    if(!isset($return[$group_id]))
        $return[$group_id] = $subarray;
    else{
        if(is_array($return[$group_id]['value']))
            array_push($return[$group_id]['value'], $subarray['value']);
        else 
            $return[$group_id]['value'] = array($subarray['value'], $return[$group_id]['value']);
    }
}

// reset grouping keys into 0,1...
$return = array_values($return);
print_r($return);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr['key1']    = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 567, 
        'value' => 780, 
    ), 
    array(
        'id'    => 676, 
        'value' => 743, 
    ), 
    array(
        'id'    => 676, 
        'value' => 721, 
    ), 
    array(
        'id'    => 234, 
        'value' => 766, 
    ), 
    array(
        'id'    => 234, 
        'value' => 780, 
    ), 
);

/* handle element merge */
function array_internal_merge_func($a, $b) {
    if ( is_array($a['value']) )
        $a['value'][]   = $b['value'];
    else 
        $a['value']     = array($a['value'], $b['value']);
    return $a;
}
/* handle array merge */
function array_internal_merge($array, $key, $merge_func) {
    $hashed = array();
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $array as $idx => $ele ) 
        $hashed[$ele[$key]][]   = $idx;
    foreach ( $hashed as $key => $idxies ) {
        reset($idxies);
        $idx0           = current($idxies);
        $result[$idx0]  = $array[$idx0];
        while ( $idx = next($idxies) ) 
            $result[$idx0]  = $merge_func($result[$idx0], $array[$idx]);
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(array_internal_merge($arr['key1'], 'id', 'array_internal_merge_func'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can certainly be done concisely with one loop.

Use `id` column values as temporary first level keys.  This makes identifying duplicates most efficient and easy.

While iterating:

1. if a row's `id` is new to the result array, then push the whole row (in its original, flat structure) into the result array; or
2. if a row's `id` was encountered before, then cast the stored row's `value` element as an array before pushing the current row's `value` into that subarray.

If you do not want your result to have `id` values as the first level keys, then call `array_values()` to re-index the result.

The special action done implemented below is that when casting a scalar or null data type to an array, the value becomes the lone element of the newly formed array.  If an array is explicitly cast as an array, then there is no effect on the data structure at all.  This is why `(array)` can be unconditionally applied in the `else` branch.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/P0Lae))

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['id']])) {
        $result[$row['id']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['id']]['value'] = array_merge(
            (array) $result[$row['id']]['value'],
            [$row['value']]
        );
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

An alternative without `array_merge()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dTWNW))

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['id']])) {
        $result[$row['id']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['id']]['value'] = (array) $result[$row['id']]['value'];
        $result[$row['id']]['value'][] = $row['value'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

An alternative with `array_reduce()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BX4gd))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            $array,
            function($result, $row) {
                if (!isset($result[$row['id']])) {
                    $result[$row['id']] = $row;
                } else {
                    $result[$row['id']]['value'] = (array) $result[$row['id']]['value'];
                    $result[$row['id']]['value'][] = $row['value'];
                }
                return $result;
            }
        )
    )
);
```