# Group array data by column value and only create indexed subarrays if more than one occurrence

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, grouping, associative-array

I need to group my multidimensional array by dates.

For example:

```
Array
(    
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 52
            [date] => 2017-07-28
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 53
            [date] => 2017-07-30
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 123
            [date] => 2017-07-30
        )
)
```

I need this result:

```
Array
(
     [2017-07-30] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 123
                    [date] => 2017-07-30
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 53
                    [date] => 2017-07-30
                )
        )    
    [2017-07-28] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 52
            [date] => 2017-07-28
        )
)
```

This is my coding attempt:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    $array = array($product['date']=>array('pid'=>$product['product_id'])‌​); 
    if(!empty($deliverdates)){ 
        if(in_array($product['date'],array_keys($_SESSION["carts‌​all"]))){ 
            foreach($deliverdates as $k => $v){
                if($product['date'] == $k){
                    array_push($deliverdates[$k], $array);
                }
            }
        }else{
            $deliverdates = array_merge($deliverdates,$array);
        }
    }else{
        $deliverdates = $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to have nested arrays for multiple answers, but only the information array otherwise? It would be easier to have nested arrays always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output array structure seems a little strange and I feel like it would make iterating it more complex than it needs to be -- but oh well.

Iterate the input array, and use the date values as keys to help you to group the data and swiftly determine if a given date is being encountered for the first time.  An `isset()` call is going to be the fastest way forward.

1. If the date **has not** been encountered yet, simply store the subarray in the result array and assign it a new key using the date.
2. If the date **has** been encountered before, then you can perform another quick check to see if the previously stored data (respective to the given date) has the `product_id` key -- this means it is an associative array and therefore contains only one "set" of data.  In this case, a structure change will need to occur.  The existing associative array for that date will need to be merged with the new associative array to form a deeper structure.  The end result for this iteration will be that the date's data structure becomes an index two-element array of associative arrays.
3. After a given date has the new "indexed array of associative arrays" stucture, any subsequent encounters of the date are simply pushed into the indexed array using bracket-syntax.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XO97G))

```
$array = [
    ['product_id' => 52, 'date' => '2017-07-28'],
    ['product_id' => 53, 'date' => '2017-07-30'],
    ['product_id' => 81, 'date' => '2017-07-26'],
    ['product_id' => 123, 'date' => '2017-07-30'],
    ['product_id' => 59, 'date' => '2017-07-26'],
    ['product_id' => 124, 'date' => '2017-07-30']
];

foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    $date = $subarray['date'];                         // not strictly necessary, but may aid code readability
    if (!isset($result[$date])) {
        $result[$date] = $subarray;                    // first encounter means no index
    } elseif (isset($result[$date]['product_id'])) {   // if associative, make indexed with associative subarrays
        $result[$date] = [$result[$date], $subarray];  // second encounter means structural change to indexed subarrays
    } else {
        $result[$date][] = $subarray;                  // beyond second encounter means push subarray into indexed structure
    }
}
krsort($result);                                       // it appears that you want DESC order
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '2017-07-30' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'product_id' => 53,
      'date' => '2017-07-30',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'product_id' => 123,
      'date' => '2017-07-30',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'product_id' => 124,
      'date' => '2017-07-30',
    ),
  ),
  '2017-07-28' => 
  array (
    'product_id' => 52,
    'date' => '2017-07-28',
  ),
  '2017-07-26' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'product_id' => 81,
      'date' => '2017-07-26',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'product_id' => 59,
      'date' => '2017-07-26',
    ),
  ),
)
```