# Array merge on basis of same keys but different keys value should add as separate array

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have data like I have pasted bellow. I want to combine on the basis of name i.e abc name template is in different language i want it in the information name, category and All its languages on the same index.

```
[{
    "name": "abc",
    "category": "new_cat",
    "selectedLanguage": [{
        "de": "Deutsch",
        "de_status": "APPROVED"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "abc",
    "category": "new_cat",
    "selectedLanguage": [{
        "en": "English",
        "en_status": "APPROVED"
    }]
}, ....
```

As mentioned above I want the result as json pasted below.

```
[{
    "name": "abc",
    "category": "new_cat",
    "selectedLanguage": [{
        "de": "Deutsch",
        "de_status": "APPROVED"
    }, {
        "en": "English",
        "en_status": "APPROVED"
    }]
},...{
    "name": "unique_temp",
    "category": "TICKET_UPDATE",
    "selectedLanguage": [{
        "en": "English",
        "en_status": "REJECTED"
    }, {
        "fr": "French",
        "fr_status": "REJECTED"
    }]

}]
```

I have written a code for it as

```
$trimArr; //this data array
$finalTempArr = array();
$finalArr = array();


 foreach ($trimArr as $tr) {
       $checkIfExist = $this ->in_array_r($wr['name'], $finalArr);
       if($checkIfExist == false){
           $finalTempArr['name'] =  $tr['name'];
           $finalTempArr['category'] =  $tr['category'];
           $finalTempArr['selectedLanguage'] =  $tr['selectedLanguage'];

       }else {
           array_push($finalTempArr['selectedLanguage'],$tr['selectedLanguage']);
       }

        array_push($finalArr, $finalTempArr);
   }
   echo json_encode($finalArr); 

function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) 
        && $this->in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If each row in your incoming array only has one child in the `selectedLanguage` subarray, then you should reduce the complexity of your data structure and just write the language and the language_status.  If you might have multiple sets of languages in those subarrays, then everything is cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `array_reduce` to accomplish it:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, static function(array $carry, array $item) {
    $key = $item['name'] . $item['category'];

    if (isset($carry[$key])) {
        $carry[$key]['selectedLanguage'] = array_merge($carry[$key]['selectedLanguage'], $item['selectedLanguage']);
    } else {
        $carry[$key] = $item;
    }

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

if you need fresh keys after reducing, then you can use `array_values` on the result:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple foreach loop will do.

> I want to combine on the basis of name

So just use the `name` as the temporary key while you group and merge the data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/j9Hnl))

```
$result = [];
foreach (json_decode($json, true) as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['name']])) {
        $result[$row['name']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['name']]['selectedLanguage'] = array_merge($result[$row['name']]['selectedLanguage'], $row['selectedLanguage']);
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

The more I think about, your subarray structure is probably not fit for purpose.  If you are eventually going to be searching for available languages to return the language status, it will be better to set up the array structure to be a "lookup".  In other words, each `selectedLanguage` subarray should be a flat associative array using the `language` as the key and the `language_status` as the value.  This would look like `"en" => "APPROVED"`.

Alternative, if your scripts are already relying on the `en` key to find the appropriate values, then keep `en` as the key and make a flat associative subarray from `en`.  I can't really say with 100% confidence what you should do, but I am reasonably sure that your data structure could be improved.  Once you ditch the indexed subarray structure, you then may be able to implement [a recursive merge/replace technique.](https://3v4l.org/Q6lNA)

Comment: I feel pretty confident that this is a duplicate question so if I find a good one, I'll hammer.

Comment: No upvotes on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27058241/2943403; this one is isn't exactly the same technique: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45264777/2943403