# Merge array with same multiple keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have this multidimensional array that  i just make

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'warehouse_zone_id' => 1,
    'warehouse_area_id' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'warehouse_zone_id' => 2,
    'warehouse_area_id' => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'warehouse_zone_id' => 3,
    'warehouse_area_id' => 3,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'warehouse_zone_id' => 4,
    'warehouse_area_id' => 3,
  ),
)
```

i want to merge the array so it become like this

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'warehouse_zone_id' => [1,2],
    'warehouse_area_id' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'warehouse_zone_id' => [3,4],
    'warehouse_area_id' => 3,
  ),
)
```

i've tried array_merge, array_merge_recursive but im not getting the results that i want

Comment: I guess you want to reduce your array with the same 'warehouse_area_id' , it's more than a simple merge.

Comment: So you want to group this by user_id and warehouse_area_id, yes? Then use the combination of both as key for your result array, that helps to accumulate the data in the right place. You can use `array_values` on the result afterwards to re-set that to a "normal" zero-based numeric index.

Comment: just updated my array.  Yes, i just want to reduce the array with the same key 'warehouse_area_id'

Comment: Somewhat related: [Group array rows by one column and only create a subarray from another column if more than one value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14496236/2943403)